# Python not saving image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Here is the code:

```
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw


def thumbnail(views):
    img = Image.open("test.jpg")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("LiberationSans.ttf", 100)
    draw.text((960, 540), views, (0, 255, 1), font=font, align='center')
    img.save("thumbnail-update.jpg")


thumbnail("1000")
```

I am using the PIL(Pillow) library.
So basically, the code runs thru with a "light speed", which is strange and the image doesn't save anywhere. Thanks for the help in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is simply that your python file cannot find the specified files test.jpg and LiberationSans.ttf. Try specifying full paths. I downloaded a font and tried the following code. On Linux you might have to use backslashes instead of / (or use os.sep).

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw


def thumbnail(views):
    img = Image.open("C:/TEST/test.jpg")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("C:/TEST/LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf", 100)  # LiberationSans.ttf
    draw.text((960, 540), views, (0, 255, 1), font=font, align='center')
    img.save("C:/TEST/thumbnail-update.jpg")


thumbnail("1000")
```

Comment: Also i am not sure how you executed your code. If you just doubleclicked the python file, try executing the code via console (python yourfile.py) to see possible errors.

Comment: Define `views="1000"` and try to run each line from the function step by step to find the error. Also validate how you imported the PIL packages, in your example you did not import PIL Image for example. It is hard to figure out if you do not provide additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm getting those errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mainproj.py", line 12, in <module>
    thumbnail("1000")
  File "mainproj.py", line 8, in thumbnail
    draw.text((960, 540), views, (0, 255, 1), font=font, align='center')
  File "C:\Users\bla\PycharmProjects\AI\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 455, in text
    ink = getink(fill)
  File "C:\Users\bla\PycharmProjects\AI\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 403, in getink
    ink, fill = self._getink(fill)
  File "C:\Users\bla\PycharmProjects\AI\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 112, in _getink
    ink = self.draw.draw_ink(ink)
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```